# Best practices in securing user's password during registration?

Tags: angular, security, passwords, frontend

I want to register a user to my app. So, I have to POST the user's password from the form on the Angular front end to the Golang back end where I'll probably encrypt it and store it in a database. However, I can't figure out what the best practice is to secure the password first, maybe at the very moment the user types it into the password registration field for the first time.

I'm new to Angular so I looked at the docs and then at 10-15 (maybe more) tutorials and so far, all the tutorials teach only how to POST, but without any security (as far as I can tell with my limited knowledge), kind of like this:

The HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input class="input" type="password" formControlName="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" (click)='register()'>Register</button>
</form>
```

The TypeScript:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: [''],
    });
...

register(){
    if(this.form.valid){
      this.http.post('/api/CreateUser', this.form.value)
      }
    }
```

I can `console.log` the password to see it in plain text. And I read (eg, [here](https://css-tricks.com/potential-dangers-of-third-party-javascript/)) that third-party JS scripts I use can access the DOM, including the password field. And, maybe there are other security issues I don't know about. So, what is the usual practice in securing a password in the context of an Angular front end that has to send it to a back end?

Comment: store password when the user is going to register. it is the only way to store password of the user.

Comment: just use https to secure data on transit